# How to find the number of factors of a number from the prime factors given that not all prime factors are distinct?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If a number has n prime factors, then logically you should be able to find the number of general factors by counting the number of ways you combine the prime factors into  1 position, 2 positions... n positions. Therefore, the number of general factors of a number,given that the number has n distinct prime factors, is equal to: [C(n,1)+C(n,2)+C(n,3)+...+C(n,n)] +1 ( I added the one to account for the fact that every number has 1 factor of 1). Because the previous series is equal to the sum of the first n C(n,k) coefficients + 1, then number of total factors is 2^n-- assuming all the prime factors are distinct; I know the formula used to count the number of ways to partition n elements when some of them are identical, but I'm having trouble applying that information to the problem. Specifically, I just think I need to know the formula for the number of ways to partition a set of objects into k positions when some of the objects are identical like a formula to count the number of ways to organize the letters of the word, e.g., MISSISSIPPI, into a word with less than 12 letters.

Comment: Note that the factor problem and the MISSISSIPPI problem are two completely different problems, as a word cares about the order of the letters in it, while a number doesn't care about the order of its prime factors.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the number with its prime factorisation $n=2^{a_1}3^{a_2} \dots p_r^{a_r}$ (we can allow $0$ as a power, as this makes no difference to the product)

Suppose $m$ is a factor of $n$. It is of the form $m=2^{b_1}3^{b_2} \dots p_r^{b_r}$ where $0\le b_i\le a_i$ (we allow $0$ as a power, which gives the factor $1$). Then there are $a_i+1$ possible values for the exponent $b_i$ (note this does work if $a_i=0$). Combining the possibilities for each prime we get the product $$(a_1+1)(a_2+1) \dots (a_r+1)$$ for the total number of factors.